# eth0 not present in OpenFiler on Hyper-V

Tags: linux, networking, hyper-v

I have installed `OpenFiler` storage sollution (based on rPath Linux) on `Hyper-V` VM and after booting into it message displays:

> You do not appear to have networking. Please login to start
>   networking.

`ifconfig` displays no eth interfaces. 
`service network restart` command gives error:

> Bringing up interface eth0: Device eth0 does not seem to be present,
>   delaying initialization.

I tried `echo > /etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules` and then `reboot` with no success.

EDIT:
I have mounted integration services and here is what i get when trying to access cd files:

[image]

Comment: What does ```ifconfig -a``` say?

Comment: If you're not seeing any interfaces at all that's usually a driver issue. If you install whatever Hyper-V's equivalent of vmware tools/guest additions and do a reboot, can you see the interfaces?

Comment: Cursory google search shows that maybe they call that software "Integration Services"

Comment: you can try also changing the eth device provided by hyper-v (if you have an option to do so). in vmware you can add different ethernet cards to a vm, and some of them do not have driver for linux. changing the device provided does the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Sundeep Seetloo
Hello there ! If you deploy openfiler on Hyper-v , the network card will not work and display this error message : "You do not appear to have networking. Please login to start networking." You must add a legacy network card, it will solve/fix the issue.